# Three backslashes in front of email address when using mailto.

Tags: xubuntu, chromium, thunderbird, email

In opening an email address with mailto in Chromium three backslashes appear in front of it in the recipient field that I have to manually remove before sending. I use Xubuntu 15.04, and Chromium opens Thunderbird with the mailto address using xdg-open, which I set to detect the default desktop as Gnome for compatibility reasons. How would I fix it so these back slashes don't appear in the first place? Attached is a screenshot. Thanks! :D[image]

Comment: Am having the exact same issue. Ubuntu 15.04 with Chromium. Adds three slashes in front of the e-mail address in a mailto: URL.